# Show that $[(\frac{p-1}{2})!]^2+1\equiv0 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let p be a prime such that $p\equiv1\mod 4$. Show that $[(\frac{p-1}{2})!]^2+1\equiv0 \pmod p$

I know I have to use Wilson's Theorem, but not sure how.

Comment: Well, compare $(p-1)!$ and $\big(\frac{p-1}2\big)!^2$. Note that for every $0<k<p$, $p-k\equiv-k\pmod p$. So, $|(p-1)!|\equiv\big|\frac{p-1}2\big|!^2\pmod p$. So when is the number of negatives the same?

Comment: I don't get it, why is $[(\frac{p-1}{2})!]^2\equiv(p-1)! \pmod p$?

Comment: Absolute values. And if you read the comment again, it'll make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo $p$, we have that $$-1\equiv (p-1)! \equiv \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \times \frac{p+1}{2} \times \frac{p+3}{2} \times \cdots p-1 \equiv \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \times -\frac{p-1}{2} \times -\frac{p-3}{2} \times \cdots (-1) \equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2$$

The result follows since $p \equiv 1 \ \text{mod} \ 4$.