# show this $\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{3}\right)!\right)^3+1\not\equiv 0\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

let $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ is prime number,show that
$$\left(\left(\dfrac{p-1}{3}\right)!\right)^3+1\not\equiv 0\pmod p$$

I know this well

[Show that $[(\frac{p-1}{2})!]^2+1\equiv0 \pmod p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447220/show-that-fracp-1221-equiv0-pmod-p?noredirect=1)

and I try use same idea to
$$-1\equiv (p-1)!=\left(\dfrac{p-1}{3}\right)!\cdot\left(\dfrac{p+2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{p+5}{3}\cdot\dfrac{p+p-2}{3}\right)\left(\cdot\dfrac{p+p+1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{p+p+4}{3}\cdots\dfrac{p+p+p-3}{3}\right)\equiv \left(\dfrac{p-1}{3}\right)!\cdot\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{5}{3}\cdots\dfrac{p-2}{3}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4}{3}\cdots\dfrac{p-3}{3}\right)\pmod p$$